# Where should I get the user id from the token for the business logic?

Tags: api, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, webapi

**Description:**
I was facing some design issues with the authorization mechanism in my ASP .NET Framework WebAPI 2 project. The application which I am working on majorly has 3 parts

1. Controllers - Endpoints
2. Services - Where shared business logic is written
3. DAL - DB calls are written

It is always a practice to get the user id (any user identification properties) from the authentication mechanism (here JWT claims).

**Problem Statement**
Where should the code for getting the user id to be written? Should it be written in the Controllers and then passed down to the Service layer or should it be accessed in the Service levels directly?

Thanks in advance.